# Class name is method type?

Tags: c#, class

Class name is `Mycal` how to call this function?

```cs
Mycal myDiv(ref Mycal calc) 
{ 
    calc.result = calc.op1 * calc.op2; 
    return calc; 
}
```

Comment: create an instance and call

Comment: `new Mycal().myDiv(ref ...)` And you should post your code fully.

Comment: No need to return calc when you send it as a ref parameter. So simply state the return type as void and remove the return statement. And for invoking this function use `myDiv(ref calc)` also by declaring the calc in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question right, it would be like this.

The function:

```
public class Mycalc
{
    public int myDiv(int op1, int op2)
    {
        int result = op1 * op2;

        return result;
    }
}
```

And calling it:

```
int result = Mycalc.myDiv(int1, int2);
```

Comment: But you've changed the signature of OP's original function `myDiv`

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** need add `ref` keword before `MyCal` because classes in **c#** are [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

```cs
public Mycal myDiv(Mycal calc) 
{ 
    calc.result = calc.op1 * calc.op2; 
    return calc; 
}
```

Then create an instance of `MyCal` and call `myDiv` method like this

```cs
new MyCal().myDiv(calc);
```

or

```cs
MyCal myCal = new MyCal();
myCal = myCal.MyDiv(cal);
```